# what is use of cURL in browser+javascript+ajax+php+mysql mix?

Tags: php, ajax, api, curl

I have an portal with AJAX calls to PHP server, and AJAX calls to a third party API.
I wanted to know what cURL can do in the mix?

What advantage it can give me. or why I should use cURL instead of AJAX?!

Comment: In other word, what possibility cURL can bring to an application. A case example would be a good answer, what is limitation of js + ajax + php is that cURL can solve?

Comment: You can use `cURL` to make http requests from php.  Ajax is for making them from the front end.  They don't have any advantages over the other they do the same thing in different realms.

Answer (score 0):

curl is something performed on the server side, in your case most likely via php.

If your php script needs to access remote data, like an API, a common method is to use curl.

curl won't replace ajax though. It can basically perform the same function as ajax, but from the server not the browser.

Comment: Thanks Bob, Yes, that is right, my application needs to access API. I have a class that uses @fsockopen for  calling API. Do I still need cURL, or is using cURL has some advantage?

Comment: I prefer curl as I find it more user friendly, but I also think that if your method isn't broken, don't fix it!